# How to write WITH tmp(id) AS (VALUES 1, 2, 3) clause in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get a list of values that do not exist in a column. The following query does exactly what I need, however I am unable to write it using the SQLAlchemy API:

```sql
WITH tmp(id) AS (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4))
SELECT tmp.id FROM tmp
LEFT JOIN Vendor
ON Vendor.id == tmp.shortname
WHERE Vendor.id IS NULL;
```

Here is my best attempt:

```python
from sqlalchemy import select, column, values, Integer # etc.

vendor_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
values_clause = values(column("id", Integer), name="tmp").data((x,) for x in vendor_ids) # Data needs to be tuples

query_nonexisting = (
    select(values_clause.c.id)
    .join(
        Vendor, onclause=Vendor.id == values_clause.c.id, isouter=True
    )
    .where(Vendor.id == None)
)
print(query_nonexisting)

session.scalars(query_nonexisting).all() # Throws SQL syntax error
```

The generated SQL statement is

```sql
SELECT tmp.id 
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS tmp(id) LEFT OUTER JOIN "Vendor" ON "Vendor".id = tmp.id
WHERE "Vendor".id IS NULL
```

which is invalid in Sqlite.

```
Result: near "(": syntax error
At line 1:
SELECT tmp.id 
FROM (VALUES ("123")) AS tmp(
```

I have tried using [CTEs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.CTE) but cannot get SQLAlchemy to generate the proper `WITH ... AS` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

SQLalchemy [does not yet support](https://groups.google.com/g/sqlalchemy/c/UhfF70QjN-U/m/qwOHGPVOAQAJ) VALUES CTE and SQLite does not support SELECT FROM VALUES syntax, which includes aliases for both table and columns. (Also see [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#common-table-expressions-cte) and [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.HasCTE.cte).) Therefore, some hacking is necessary. The following should do the job:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, MetaData, select, values, text

metadata = MetaData()

Vendor = Table('Vendor', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer)
)

ids_values = \
    values(
        Column('column1', Integer),
        name="tmp_anon",
        literal_binds=True
    ).data(
        [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
    )

tmp_anon = \
    text(
        str(ids_values)
    ).columns(Column('column1', Integer)).cte("tmp_anon")
tmp = select(tmp_anon.c.column1.label('id')).cte("tmp")

query_nonexisting = \
    select(
        tmp.c.id
    ).join(
        Vendor, onclause=Vendor.c.id == tmp.c.id, isouter=True
    ).where(Vendor.c.id == None)
       
print(query_nonexisting)
```